# cmd: Can't find service: activity #Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

after updating android studio, i run my flutter program.

Error is showing that

```dart
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
cmd: Can't find service: activity
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\Tutorial3\flutter_ecommerce\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on AOSP on IA Emulator.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Open AVD Manager
- Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)
- Open emulator
- Try to run app

Comment: "wipe data" sounds like a clever step, until this happens on your phone

Answer (score 0):

If your issues is with Visual Studio
Click on Tools
Click on Android
Open Android Device Manager
Wipe Data (delete data from emulator)
Open emulator
Try to run app

or

just run the emulator go to the phone's settings and uninstall the app simple

u probably clean ur dll and exe and then u run it that's why u are getting this error rebuild the solution