# Flutter2 - Can't find service: package (Android Studio -Windows10)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

On upgrading a working project to Flutter_2 and running it , gives the error below.

[As per answer to  similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61145818/cmd-cant-find-service-activity-error-adb-exited-with-exit-code-1-in-flutter) ,Avd Data(Pixel_3a) has been `wiped`.

How to resolve this ?

***ERROR***

```
Can't find service: package /  Can't find service: activity
```

***FULL ERROR***

```
Launching lib\forms\validateForm1.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
cmd: Can't find service: activity
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install
    
adb: failed to install F:\Script\Flutter\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on sdk gphone x86 arm.
```

***Flutter Doctor***

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-10.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: Class `two`'s constructor takes (optional) *named* arguments, not positional ones.  Either remove the curly braces (`{` and `}`) from its constructor's parameter list to make them positional, or invoke its constructor as `two(a: 4, b: 5, c: 6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting Avd related `lock files` resolved the issue.

Open Avd Manager -> ShowonDisk -> Delete following 2 lock files from disk --->

hardware-qemu & multiinstance.lock

Comment: doesn't work for me, I did rm ~/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_30.avd/*.lock still cant find service: activity